# Silverlight 4, data binding and dynamic objects

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, dynamic

I have a control which uses the old-style data biding via *MemberPath properties. However, my situation requires the usage of a DynamicObject. When you get the type of that dynamic object and call GetProperty(..) it returns null (because the object itself does not contain such a property - it is a dynamic one). So.. how can I solve this issue? How can I bind an object with dynamic properties having that the view uses that old-style data binding approach?

Answer (score 1):

You're somewhat out of luck in Silverlight 4.  Silverlight 5 (in beta) has the ICustomTypeProvider interface to allow binding to dynamic properties, but Silverlight 4 doesn't have this.  Until Silverlight 5 is released, you have two options:

1) Write a value converter to get the value from the object.

OR

2) Have an indexer on your object that when passed a "property" name, returns the corresponding value.  You can then extract the value like so:

```
Binding="{Binding [PropertyName]}"
```

Option 2 is the best option IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot use binding like this, because I have *MemberPath properties (which in the background call obj.GetType().GetProperty(...))